# Add SCons files to ack searches

Tags: scons, ack

I love the code search utility `ack`. It is smart enough to look through Makefiles, but doesn't know about the SConstruct and SConscript files that scons uses. How do I add those to the files that ack will look in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done using ack's type sets. [Makefiles and Rakefiles are hard-coded](https://github.com/petdance/ack/blob/78dac543626aec534f6d717cdc85a435b479ab1b/Ack.pm#LC503) in the source. I thought you could add a scons type by modifying `$HOME/.ackrc` and adding `--type-set=scons=SConstruct,SConscript`, but that will search for a file that ends in ".SConstruct" or ".SConscript".

The easiest workaround is to add the -a (all file types) flag to ack.

If you just want ack to search and be able to filter the SConstruct somehow, then you could add `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of the SConstruct file. Ack will then treat the file as python source code, and you can filter with `--python`.

Comment: That only seems to work for .scons files, not SConstruct or SConscript.

Comment: Gah, you're right. Just checked the source - "makefile" and "rakefile" are hard-coded exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up. I was able to modify my local version to add SConstruct and SConscript in the same way makefiles are in there, maybe I'll submit a patch. I must say I'm not crazy about the scons design decision to use files w/out extensions, though I've seen other build systems that do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a patch that treats SCons files like make files:

```
--- ~/bin/ack-old 2011-06-01 15:43:51.000000000 -0600
+++ ~/bin/ack     2011-06-01 15:42:09.000000000 -0600
@@ -1583,6 +1583,8 @@

     return 'skipped' unless is_searchable( $basename );

+    return ('python',TEXT)      if $basename eq 'SConstruct' || $basename eq 'SConscript';
+
     my $lc_basename = lc $basename;
     return ('make',TEXT)        if $lc_basename eq 'makefile' || $lc_basename eq 'gnumakefile';
     return ('rake','ruby',TEXT) if $lc_basename eq 'rakefile';
```

Comment: I'm running the deb package of ack version 1.92 on Ubuntu 10.04, and the same patch can be manually applied to /usr/share/perl5/App/Ack.pm at around line 476.

Answer (score 1):

A new [ack2](http://groups.google.com/group/ack-users/browse_thread/thread/ed5890032506496e) is in development which will allow exact file matching in the .ackrc file. That will enable easier support for Scons and Jam.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508431/ack-binding-an-actual-file-name-to-a-filetype for more on this.